# PHP source code in LaTeX

Tags: listings, code

Can somebody please show the correct way to display my source code in LaTeX?

I want to display the following PHP code:

```
$id = addslashes($_GET['id']);
```

I tried to do it as follows, but I get an error about a label that has not yet been referenced:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
$id = addslashes($_GET['id']);
\label{phpheg}
\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) of the `listings` package, you have to define the `caption` and `label` in the options of the `lstlisting` environment. This is required because any text within `lstlisting` is typeset, so your code prints `\label{phpheg}` in the PDF, instead of calling that as a LaTeX command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
    See Listing~\ref{phpheg} for details.
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={PHP Code},label=phpheg]
$id = addslashes($_GET['id']);
\end{lstlisting}
    More text.
\end{document}
```

Note: as Werner says in his comment, as *everything* between `\begin{lstlisting}` and `\end{lstlisting}` is printed, thus indented code is also typeset indented. As a work-around, you can (and should) write the listing without any indention (as above).

As proposed by MaxNoe, you can use the `lstautogobble` package as a workaround: simply add `\usepackage{autogobble}` and set `autogobble=true` in the settings of `lstlistings`.

Comment: Be aware that indenting your `lstlisting` environment as well as the code contained within it may result in indentation when setting it.

Comment: there's lstautogobble

Comment: Thanks for you inputs, I tried to make that more clear in my answer.